# STATA: Demean and Detrend after Dickey-Fuller do not reduce p-value to insignificant levels

Tags: p-value, stata, augmented-dickey-fuller

Please see below the process I have followed in STATA and help me understand whether I have done it correctly. The issue is that after de-mean-ing and de-trend-ing time-series (after Dickey-Fuller) the p-value is still significant.

Process:

```
summarize cayi_cta_40
dfuller cayi_cta_40
```

[image]

de-mean:

```
gen dem1_cayi_cta_40= cayi_cta_40-r(mean)
```

de-trend

```
reg dem1_cayi_cta_40 mydate

predict det_ cayi_cta_40, resid
```

and run the dfuller on the new de-meaned and de-trended data:

```
dfuller det_cayi_cta_40
```

[image]

The p-value is still significant, can you please advise. Thanks

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about the motivation and expectation. Why are you expecting the p-value to be insignificant? What is your threshold for insignificant?

Comment: Motivation: test time-series. Expectation: none (but if the unit root present then demean and detrend). I would imagine it should be insignificant in post-processing (demean and detrend), no? Threshold for the MAcKinnon p-value: 0.05